# Creating a new array 'cell' and moving all previous ones down

Tags: swift, date

Basically i have a tableView where i  save a date... then i want to save another date, and push the first date from '0' in array to '1' position, while populating '0' with new date

```
let now = Date()
var date = ""
```

This creates a date ^^

```
 var list = [ String(date) ]
```

this  is the array ^^

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
   // print(dateFormatter.string(from: now))
    date = (dateFormatter.string(from: now))
```

This turns raw date into an easy to read string ^^

I want to make a function that Saves that string in the array, moves it down and creates a new one with new date

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the array of date strings like this

```
var dates = [String]()
```

then create the date string

```
let now = Date() 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
```

then insert it in the array at index 0

```
 dates.insert(dateStr, at: 0)
```

Comment: You would also need to reload the table view or insert the row at the correct index path.